# Dragging windows between workspaces in 14.10

Tags: workspaces, 14.10, application-switcher, drag-and-drop

Quick question:

Has dragging windows between workspaces been partly disabled in the new release 14.10?
I can only drag left-right with `ctrl+alt+shift+arrow`. Dragging up-down does not work.
Can it be restored?

Answer (score 0):

I know about its replacement in Ubuntu 14.04. You need to go to System Settings in Appearance. Select Behavior tab. Enable workspaces. You will get a workspace switcher on the launcher as well as workspaces will work now. Now try your tricks. If they don't work, my way is to click the workspace button and drag the windows.